# CyberGhost on Linux

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I need to use the CyberGhost free plan on Linux. However, when looking installation instructions, one of the preconditions was:

"You need a CyberGhost subscription (the Free Service doesn't include support of native protocols)"

What does this mean? What does "native protocols" mean? Will I be able to use OpenVPN on Linux with the free version?

Here is a link to what I was looking at: https://support.cyberghostvpn.com/hc/en-us/articles/213190329-Read-me-first-How-to-use-CyberGhost-with-Linux

Comment: this looks like a question for the vendor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's explained right on the page:

> Your CyberGhost subscription can be used smoothly with many Linux distributions, if the respective one supports at least one of the **native protocols OpenVPN, PPTP, IPSec or L2TP**.
>
> [...] the Free Service doesn't include support of native protocols [...]

[(Source)](https://support.cyberghostvpn.com/hc/en-us/articles/213190329-Read-me-first-How-to-use-CyberGhost-with-Linux)

> Will I be able to use OpenVPN on Linux with the free version?

OpenVPN is a "native protocol", ergo you can't use it with the free version.